# Selenium Testing Extent Report is generating no Log inside HTML

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Extent Report to my project and here is the way of reporting.

I test all the values and they are present on my site.
I want to print all the Log in Extent Report.
I have written code but it's not generating Log in my output HTML file.

Anyone can suggest me how to add log?

```
@Test
public void AnalyticsCode() {
    wd.manage().window().maximize();
    wd.get("https://www.google.com");
    test.log(Status.INFO,"************homePage*********************");
    java.lang.String Source = wd.getPageSource();
    test.log(Status.INFO,"Google Analytics Code is Present : " + Source.contains("UA-460962-1"));
    test.log(Status.INFO,"Google Tag Manager Code is Present : "
            + Source.contains("id=GTM-NKBC"));
    wd.close();
    wd = new ChromeDriver();
    wd.get("https://www.google.com/usa");
    test.log(Status.INFO,"************Listpage*********************");
    java.lang.String Source_cat = wd.getPageSource();
    test.log(Status.INFO,"Google Analytics Code is Present : " + Source_cat.contains("UA-460270-1"));
    test.log(Status.INFO,"Google Tag Manager Code is Present : " + Source_cat.contains("id=GTM-NFSBC"));
    wd.close();
    wd = new ChromeDriver();
    wd.get("https://www.google.com/comparison.html");
    test.log(Status.INFO,"************IM comparison.html *********************");
    java.lang.String Source_com = wd.getPageSource();
    test.log(Status.INFO,"Google Tag Manager Code is Present : " + Source_com.contains("GTM-SKBC"));
    wd.close();
}
```

Comment: your question is very hard to be understood at the moment. It's not clear what you mean by `Extent Report`. It's not clear either if you want to use Selenium to change some report already generated in its HTML. Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to make it clear?

Comment: you should learn selenium with extentreports.com then you can understand this question

Comment: Extend Report doesn't look very popular. It doesn't even have a `tag` here in StackOverflow (maybe you can create one to explain what it is). I believe that, if you really want help, it would make your life easier clarify those things, maybe at least adding a link to it in your question. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, tom, I already solve and I will post it here and next time I will ask any question by details if the framework is unknown.Thanks